# calculate function in javascript for MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function compute(calcval, val)
{
    var txtweeklyMailing = Number(document.getElementById(val).value);
    var total = txtweeklyMailing * 25;
    var _total = total.toFixed(2);
    var _stotal = _total + '';
    document.getElementById(calcval).value = _stotal;
    }
</script>   
<p>Number of weekly mailings @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.WeeklyMailings, new { id = "weeklymailing", onblur = "return:compute('txtpostcardperweek', 'weeklymailing')" }) x 25</p>
<p>=</p>
<p>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PostcardsperWeek, new Dictionary<string, object>() { {"id", "txtpostcardperweek"}, { "readonly", "true" } }) Total postcards per week</p>
```

I would need to use an onblur for a textbox to calculate what a user would enter by 25 and display the result in a textbox below. How would i pass in the textbox values in the onblur event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(
    m => m.WeeklyMailings, 
    new { 
        id = "weeklymailing", 
        onblur = "compute('txtpostcardperweek', 'weeklymailing')" 
    }
)
```

or if you want to use unobtrusive javascript with jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#weeklymailing').blur(function () {
            var txtweeklyMailing = Number($(this).val());
            var total = txtweeklyMailing * 25;
            $('#txtpostcardperweek').val(total.toFixed(2));
        });
    });
</script>   
<p>
    Number of weekly mailings 
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.WeeklyMailings, new { id = "weeklymailing" }) 
    x 25
</p>
<p>=</p>
<p>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PostcardsperWeek, new { id = "txtpostcardperweek", @readonly = "readonly" }) 
    Total postcards per week
</p>
```

Personally I prefer the second approach as you are not mixing javascript and markup which reduces the size of your html pages and you could put the javascript into a separate static file which could be cached by the client browser.

Comment: Thanks Darin. I used the second option. Thanks a lot.